# Grails: belongsTo cache issue

Tags: hibernate, caching, grails

Hi guys have a problem with cache, please help
Have 2 entities

```
class User {
   FacebookUser facebookUser
   static mapping {
      cache true
   }
   def getImage() {
      return facebookUser.image
   }
}
```

And

```
class FacebookUser {
   static belongsTo = [user:User]
   static mapping = {
      cache true
   }
}
```

When getting a user from cache it always try to select a user with facebook_user_id = ?.
But when I remove belongsTo it's work as I wish. So I have a question: Why?
Thanks

showing a queries generated by Hibernate

```
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id69_3_, ... from user user0_ left outer join fb_user facebookus1_ on user0_.facebook_user_id=facebookus1_.id where user0_.id=?

Hibernate: select user0_.id as id69_3_, ... from user user0_ left outer join fb_user facebookus1_ on user0_.facebook_user_id=facebookus1_.id where user0_.facebook_user_id=?
```

First query hibernate caches but second always executed
If I remove belongsTo nothing changes but second query never appears